# Object is possibly null in TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With this code:

```js
const Products = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { data } = useFetch('/categories');

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <GridList cellHeight={180} className={classes.gridList}>
        <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={6} style={{ height: 'auto' }} />
        {data &&
          data.map((category: CategoryInterface) => {
            return (
              <GridListTile key={category.id}>
                <GridListTileBar title={category.name} />
              </GridListTile>
            );
          })}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I get 'Object is possibly null' on data before the map, I tried using the && operator to get rid of it and I also tried defining a variable like `const categories = data as CategoryInterface[]` but that showed me I had to convert to unknown first, how should I do this instead?

Here is the useFetch hook

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useFetch = (url: string) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ data: null, loading: true });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(state => ({ data: state.data, loading: true }));

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => setState({ data: json, loading: false }));
  }, [url, setState]);

  return state;
};
```

Comment: how does your data look like? is it an array?

Comment: I added the code, it has type null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript assign types to JavaScript variables. Mostly when you use TS you should define variables types before usage. However TS sometimes can infer types of variables if possible.

It seems that you copy-paste JS code into TypeScript and trying to make it work. So first of all I suggest to define types for variables you're going to use, so TS will set correct types.

Initial call to `useState` makes `state.data` of type `null` (that is the only TS knows about it type). And unlike JS, TS doesn't allow to change type during execution. So `state.data` will have `null` type during program execution.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ data: null, loading: true });
// Type of state is
// { data: null, loading: boolean }
```

To correct this you should provide type of your `state` variable ahead of time. One possible value of it is `null`. Another possible value - is data received from `fetch`. You probably should know what is type JSON structure of returned data from `fetch` so type it accordinately.

From your code I can guess, that data type will probably look like this

```
type IData = CategoryInterface[];
```

And `CategoryInterface` may look like

```
interface CategoryInterface {
    id: string;
    name: string; 
}
```

So `IData` will be second possible type of `state.data`. So assign type of `state` during `useState` call

```
const [state, setState] = useState<{data: IData | null, loading: boolean}>({ data: null, loading: true });
```

But you should leave in place `{data && data.map (/*...*/)}` as `state.data` will be undefined until data fully loaded.

Full code

```
interface CategoryInterface {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

type IData = CategoryInterface[];

export const useFetch = (url: string) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<{ data: IData | null, loading: boolean }>({ data: null, loading: true });

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(state => ({ data: state.data, loading: true }));

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => setState({ data: json, loading: false }));
    }, [url, setState]);

    return state;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed from a JS project

Answer (score 0):

Your `useFetch` hook should be like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useFetch = (url: string) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ data: {}, loading: true }); //Don't assign null to state variable

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(state => ({ data: state.data, loading: true })); //Remove this line, this is not needed 

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => setState({ data: json, loading: false }));
  }, [url, setState]); //Replace [url, setState] with [] as your second argument to make useEffect work for first time.

  return state;
};
```

And your usage should be:

```
const { data } = useFetch('/categories');

{data.length>0 &&
  data.map((category: CategoryInterface) => {
    return (
      <GridListTile key={category.id}>
        <GridListTileBar title={category.name} />
      </GridListTile>
    );
  })
}
```