# Typescript React useRef object possibly null (Uncontrolled Component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use a ref to an input element, and then use `inputRef.current.value` to get its value
but I'm getting an error `Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)`  at `inputRef.current`.

I tried several different solutions but I haven't got it to work yet. Any help is appreciated.

```
interface RefObject<T> {
    readonly current: T | null
  }
  
const Uncontrolled: React.FC = () => {
    // const inputRef = useRef< HTMLInputElement | null> (null);
    const inputRef:RefObject<HTMLInputElement> = useRef< HTMLInputElement | null> (null);
    
    function alertValue() {
        alert(inputRef.current.value);         //Object is possibly 'null', under inputRef.current
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p> Uncontrolled components do not have state data</p>
            <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
            <button onClick={alertValue}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

my solutions came from:

[useRef TypeScript - not assignable to type LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963289/useref-typescript-not-assignable-to-type-legacyrefhtmldivelement)

[Object is possibly null in TypeScript React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801439/object-is-possibly-null-in-typescript-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use optional chaining or `!` to assert that the `.current` property isn't nullish...

```
alert(inputRef.current!.value);
```

a better way would be to make the input *controlled* and log the state instead.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
function alertValue() {
    alert(value);
}
// ...
<input value={value} onchange={e => { setValue(e.currentTarget.value); }} />
```

Comment: Thanks, the ! worked, I'll look into optional chaining too. for this component I'm trying to make it uncontrolled on purpose hence the component name. I'll accept answer in 8 mins